# get mplayer to start with a default volume other than 25%

Tags: mplayer

I want to configure mplayer conf so that the player's default volume is not 25%. I have to increase the volume via the keyboard with every song/flick. I can only find solutions that simply over-pushing the soundcard...

Answer (score 7):

You can run mplayer with the -af flag:

```
mplayer -af volume=10:1
```

where the value 10 means the sound is amplified by 10dB

To set this, edit the mplayer configuration file:

```
 ~/.mplayer/config
```

add the option:

```
af=volume=10:1
```

The af flag alters the hardware volume. If this doesn't work, you can try specifying the software mixer, and altering the software volume with the options:

```
softvol=yes
softvol-max=1000
```

Comment: appears that -af volume=10:1 avoids using a software mixer at all, which allows mutes to work better than using softvol. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

The -volume option sets the volume between 0 and 100.

```
mplayer -volume 40 MyMusicVideo.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a different problem, but it's the skin that breaks the volume setting for me. Here's my fix:

```
diff -u /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/skin{.bak,}
--- /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/skin.bak   2015-09-08 23:15:31.000000000 +0200
+++ /usr/share/mplayer/skins/default/skin   2019-10-16 09:40:01.152006731 +0200
@@ -38,7 +38,7 @@
   ;hpotmeter=buttonbitmaps,sx,sy,phasebitmaps,phases,default value,x,y,sx,sy,msg
   hpotmeter = pos, 13, 10, NULL, 100,  0, 242, 79, 82, 10, evSetMoviePosition
   hpotmeter = pos, 13, 10, NULL,  50, 50,  78, 59, 42, 10, evSetBalance
-  hpotmeter = pos, 13, 10, NULL,  50, 50,  79, 78, 44, 10, evSetVolume
+  hpotmeter = pos, 13, 10, NULL,  50, -,  79, 78, 44, 10, evSetVolume
 
   ;pimage=phasebitmaps,phases,default value,x,y,sx,sy,msg
 ;  pimage = progres-long2c, 46, 0, 245, 67, 141, 5, evSetMoviePosition
```